# upgraded server from 2016 to 2019 with storage pool. Should I run Update-StoragePool to upgrade the version?

Tags: windows-server-2016, upgrade, windows-server-2019, storage-spaces

I in-place upgraded a server 2016 box with a storage pool to server 2019. Everything is running fine though the pool version is "Windows Server 2016". Should I run the Update-StoragePool command to update it to "Windows Server 2019"? Has anyone else done this from 2016 to 2019 and has it worked fine? How long does the command usually take (the pools is a simple mirrored pool of 2 500GB ssd's)?

Thank you,

Comment: ok so the impatient part of my won out and this morning I ran full backups of everything on the pool and then ran the command. Well for anyone interested the only change I notice is the version now says "Windows Server 2019". The command didn't take any time to complete. I did do a reboot after the results checked out to make sure I was in a clean state and all is good. My main question now is what did running this command do for me?